# How to populate the option values dynamically inside a dropdown which is build on onclick event of a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php

In the on click event of a select drop-down, how to dynamically create a drop-down menu , which is also created inside the function [for options : fetch the data from the database].

I have 2 drop-down menus in my page with id="type" , first drop down menu is rendered on page load itself, fetching the data from database.
And the second drop-down menu is built inside the on click event[function] of the first drop-down.

For rendering the second drop-down menu I have made an ajax call, but only for the first time, the drop-down menu with options is getting rendered, on clicking the button multiple times, no action is getting performed.

This is my page :

type.php

```
<?php

include('db.php');

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" enctype="multipart/formdata" method="POST" autocomplete="off">


<table id="table" class=" table order-list">
<thead>
<tr>
<td><b>Type</b></td>
</tr>
<div id="next"></div>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="col-sm-3">
<select class="form-control" name="type[]" id="type" required>
<option value="">Select the Type</option>
<?php

$arr = array();
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"select id,name from type_table where view = 'display'");
while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    echo '<option value="'.$result['id'].'">'.$result['name'].'</option>';
    $arr[$result['id']] = $result['name'];  
}

?>
</select>   
</td>

<td class="col-sm-2"><a class="deleteRow"></a> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block " id="addrow" value="Add Row" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>        
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-12">
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="submit" class="btn btn-success center-block" id="submittable">
</div>
</div>                       
</form>                                       

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var arr = <?php echo json_encode($arr);?>;
//console.log(arr);
document.getElementById("addrow").onclick = function () {

  $.ajax({
  url:"test_select.php",
  method:"post",
  data:{arr:arr},
  success:function(data){
       $('#next').html(data);
  } 
  });
}

$("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
$(this).closest("tr").remove();       
counter -= 1
});

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the ajax call made file [test_mail.php]:

```
<?php


//print_r($_POST["arr"]);
$select = '';

$select = '<tr><td><select class="form-control" name="type[]" id="type" required>';
foreach($_POST["arr"] as $k=>$v){
    $select .= '<option value="'.$k.'">'.$v.'</option>';
}

$select .= '</select></td><td class="col-sm-2"><a class="deleteRow"></a> </td></tr>';

echo $select;

?>
```

I expect to get the second drop down [inside the on click event of a button ] to be rendered dynamically as many times I click the button .

Comment: `I have 2 drop down menus in my page with id="type"`  That would be your first problem.  Element ids should be unique.

Comment: Your second (and most relevant) issue is `$('#next').html(data);`  The [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) function does a replacement of the content in the matched element.  You probably want something like [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/#append-content-content)

Comment: k.I have removed the id attribute of first drop down menu . What I need to do for the second issue you specified.

Comment: Follow the link that I provided and see if the suggested function meets your desired functionality.  If so, implement it.

Comment: where is the link

Comment: @GayathriA they are in the second comment

Answer (score 1):

First off, I am quite sure that you're asking about *dropdown* menu (usually a <kbd>select</kbd> form input, also known as *dropdown* or *combobox*) "on-click" event and not a <kbd>button</kbd> on-click as mentioned in the question.

["On-click" event (as explained here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) occures when the user "clicks" with his mouse on an element (or may also be triggered by any pointer like devices).
But what you are looking for is ["on-change"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) event which will be fired every time when you change your selection within the select form input.

Please go through the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) and modify your code accordingly.

Comment: If you look at the code, you'll see that OP is binding the onclick to the element with the id "addrow", which is a button, not a dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure if you are talking about onclick event of the button `$('.addrow')` or of the select element `$('#type')`, I have spotted an issue which is the reason why no select is being rendered the second time and so on.

Using html() will replace everything inside an element. So everytime user clicks on `$('.addrow')` button, it will replace everything inside the targeted element `$('#next')`

You should use the jquery append() method:

```
$.ajax({
  url:"test_select.php",
  method:"post",
  data:{arr:arr},
  success:function(data){
     $('#next').append(data);
  } 
});
```

Link to docs: https://api.jquery.com/append/